# CSVHelper - ignore blank cells in a row unless they are populated

Tags: c#, csvhelper

Using CsvHelper with .NET Core 2.2.

We're parsing a CSV file to then export to a SQL table.  There are two different mappings of the CSV columns to the SQL columns, which depend on the first value of each row of the CSV.

This is what we have:

```
 public List<TaskProdEntity> ParseCSVFile()
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\pfile.csv"))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
            {
                csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = (string header, int index) =>
                    header.Replace(" ", "_").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace(".", "");

                List<TaskProdEntity> records = new List<TaskProdEntity>();

                csv.Read();
                csv.ReadHeader();

                while (csv.Read())
                {
                    if (csv.GetField<int>(0) == 1)
                    {
                        var record = new TaskProdEntity
                        {

                            Identifier = "ID Number:" + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Id"),   
                            Region = "Business Mailing Address:" + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Provider_First_Line_Business_Mailing_Address") + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Provider_Second_Line_Business_Mailing_Address") + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Provider_Business_Mailing_Address_City_Name") + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Provider_Business_Mailing_Address_State_Name") + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Provider_Business_Mailing_Address_Postal_Code") + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Provider_Business_Mailing_Address_Country_Code_If_outside_US") + " | " + "Business Practice Location:" + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Provider_First_Line_Business_Practice_Location_Address") + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Provider_Second_Line_Business_Practice_Location_Address") + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_City_Name") + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_State_Name") + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_Postal_Code") + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_Country_Code_If_outside_US"),
                            Program = "Taxonomy Group:" + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Taxonomy_Group_1")

                        };

                        records.Add(record);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var record = new TaskProdEntity
                        {

                            Identifier = "ID Number:" + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Id3"),   
                            Region = "Business Mailing Address:" + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Provider_First_Line_Business_Mailing_Address2") + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Provider_Second_Line_Business_Mailing_Address2") + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Provider_Business_Mailing_Address_City_Name2") + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Provider_Business_Mailing_Address_State_Name2") + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Provider_Business_Mailing_Address_Postal_Code2") + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Provider_Business_Mailing_Address_Country_Code_If_outside_US2") + " | " + "Business Practice Location:" + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Provider_First_Line_Business_Practice_Location_Address2") + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Provider_Second_Line_Business_Practice_Location_Address2") + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_City_Name2") + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_State_Name2") + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_Postal_Code2") + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Provider_Business_Practice_Location_Address_Country_Code_If_outside_US2"),
                            Program = "Taxonomy Group:" + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Taxonomy_Group_2")
                        };
                        records.Add(record);    
                    }
                }
               return records;
            }             
        }
```

Because the mapping for the `Region` field specifically is so messy and long, I really want to extract values from those csv fields only if the field is not blank.  In many cases, many of those fields will be blank, and the business does not want a ton of concatenated blanks to end up in the database in these cases.

I am wondering if CsvHelper already has a built-in function to achieve this?  If not, how would I implement that logic into the above code?

Comment: CsvHelper does not have a built-in function to achieve your requirements.  You would need to implement the logic yourself, I would recommend creating a separate method `Region = GetAddress(csv)`.  Just curious why you would put all the address info into one line in the database instead of as separate columns that are put back together when you query the database.  If the format for the address was to change, those records are going to be difficult to modify.

Comment: Yes great question and unfortunately we are having to export this to an already-established schema for this database table.  The Region field is where they want it all.  I agree with you that it's not the best approach, but this table has existed for years and holds all kinds of other records.  They want us to basically force the contents of this csv file into the existing schema of that table.

Answer (score 1):

Since the second `TaskProdEntity` appears to add a 2 each time to the column header, you could have one method that builds your address.

```cs
public List<TaskProdEntity> ParseCSVFile()
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\pfile.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
    {
        csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = (string header, int index) =>
            header.Replace(" ", "_").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace(".", "");

        List<TaskProdEntity> records = new List<TaskProdEntity>();

        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();

        while (csv.Read())
        {
            if (csv.GetField<int>(0) == 1)
            {
                var record = new TaskProdEntity
                {

                    Identifier = "ID Number:" + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Id"),
                    Region = GetAddress(csv),
                    Program = "Taxonomy Group:" + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Taxonomy_Group_1")

                };

                records.Add(record);

            }
            else
            {
                var record = new TaskProdEntity
                {

                    Identifier = "ID Number:" + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Id3"),
                    Region = GetAddress(csv, "2"),
                    Program = "Taxonomy Group:" + " " + csv.GetField<string>("Taxonomy_Group_2")
                };
                records.Add(record);
            }
        }
        return records;
    }
}

private string GetAddress(CsvReader csv, string extension = "")
{
    var value = new StringBuilder("Business Mailing Address:");

    if (csv.GetField<string>("Provider_First_Line_Business_Mailing_Address" + extension) != string.Empty)
    {
        value.Append(" " + csv.GetField<string>("Provider_First_Line_Business_Mailing_Address" + extension));
    }

    if (csv.GetField<string>("Provider_Second_Line_Business_Mailing_Address" + extension) != string.Empty)
    {
        value.Append(" " + csv.GetField<string>("Provider_Second_Line_Business_Mailing_Address" + extension));
    }

    // The rest of the if statements..............

    return value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Hi David.  I am not sure I understand what you mean when you say "Since the second `TaskProdEntity` appears to add a 2 each time to the column header..."  Can you clarify that?

Comment: The first `TaskProdEntity` has `"Provider_First_Line_Business_Mailing_Address"` and the second has `"Provider_First_Line_Business_Mailing_Address2"`.  The method `GetAddress()` is able to take the `extension = "2"` in `GetAddress(csv, "2")` and add it to each column so the one method works for both.